# Why does Stack Exchange (and Stack Overflow in particular) make it so hard for new contributors to participate?

Tags: discussion, reputation, new-users

I've been a lurker (or consumer) of Stack Overflow for as long as I can think back (it definitely feels longer than the 12 years the site exists).
During that time, I've often felt the impulse to add to what is already there. But apparently that will never happen. How will I ever earn the reputation that is needed for contributing if I may not contribute?

And, duly noted, I will never gather the hubris to say "I've got a completely new question that was never asked before", and  beware much less will I claim to have an answer. No, I want to contribute in form of refinements, and the perfect way to do this would be comments.

So tough luck, one less contributor, I guess I will stay consumer.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can contribute refinements by suggesting edits and you can do that with a starting reputation of 1.

If your suggested edits get approved then you score 2 reputation points for each of them.

Enough of these and you can reach the comment anywhere privilege at 50 reputation points.

Using this route you need never ask or answer a question in order to be able to comment anywhere.

Comment: until you hit 3k, assuming a reasonable amount of accepts :D

Comment: Honest Opinion: Do you think it would kill the UI/UX/SE to add a hint to that effect to the message denying the comment?

Comment: @TorgeHusfeldt You could ask that as a another question but be sure to search for whether it’s already been asked first.

Answer (score 4):

I feel like one of the big "mistakes" of how the Stack Exchange network as a whole is promoted is that it's "a place to ask questions" as opposed to "a place to find answers"

I have *about* 120k reputation on one site, and about 91k on another. Ironically enough, it's the site where I kinda lost my way to 10k that's the most informative here.

*Typically* I'm looking for answers, or to contribute an answer to an existing question. One finds there's often multiple approaches to a problem and in a few cases I've posted a new answer to an old question that was well received.

I suspect another problem here is well "Why can't I do all these things all at once?" As a meta mod/user I can attest appropriate commentary is hard. Some folks use it as a "risk free" way to share a quick answer without spending the effort, or risking the downvotes to post a full answer. The system is meant to ease people into the way we do things, slowly.

> I will never gather the hubris to say "I've got a completely new question that was never asked before", and beware much less will I claim to have an answer.

And yet, this happens. I've often had some obscure little problem for some hobby project and I *didn't* find an answer. I asked a question and the information is now available to others.

> No, I want to contribute in form of refinements, and the perfect way to do this would be comments.

Commenting does need 50 reputation, but *all* it needs you to do is to get 200 reputation on *one* site, *anywhere* or get five upvotes on the site in question.

It's not a huge investment in time.

If you want to contribute, you're free to, *but* the system is really set up to ease new users into some of the quirks of the system.

Comment: [Commenting is >= 50 reputation on SO.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment)

Comment: Wow, just wow. So obviously I must be an especially daft "new" user _"but the system is really set up to ease new users into some of the quirks of the system"_